# how to create a DF from a DF based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas

My current DF looks like this

```
Combinations               Count
1   ('IDLY', 'VADA')       3734
6   ('DOSA', 'IDLY')        2020
9   ('CHAPPATHI', 'DOSA')   1297
10  ('IDLY', 'POORI')       1297
11  ('COFFEE', 'TEA')       1179
13  ('DOSA', 'VADA')        1141
15  ('CHAPPATHI', 'IDLY')   1070
16  ('COFFEE', 'SAMOSA')    1061
17  ('COFFEE', 'IDLY')      1016
18  ('POORI', 'VADA')       1008
```

Lets say I filter by the keyword 'DOSA' from above data frame I get the below OP

```
    Combinations           Count
6   ('DOSA', 'IDLY')        2020
9   ('CHAPPATHI', 'DOSA')   1297
13  ('DOSA', 'VADA')        1141
```

But I would like the output to be like the df below(which has ignored the filter key word as its common,

```
    Combinations    Count
6   IDLY            2020
9   CHAPPATHI       1297
13  VADA            1141
```

What concept of pandas needs to be used here? How can this be achieved?

Comment: Dear Paul , Thanks for your offer , also I understand you could be frustrated assuming i am seeking someone to write the code for me. Actually no , i have been stuck with this for a week, went through many tutorials ! And that is why I also asked what 'Concept' needs to be used , so that I would try to work on those concepts. Sorry if my question gave you a wrong idea, expecting someone to write code for me , was not my intention at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it's not ideal to have `list, tuples, sets,` etc inside a dataframe. It's better to have multiple records for each instance when needed.

You can use `explode` turn `Combinations` into this form and filter on that

```
keyword = 'DOSA'

s = df.explode('Combinations')

s.loc[s.Combinations.eq('keyword').groupby(level=0).transform('any') & s.Combinations.ne('keyword')]
```

Or chain the two commands with `.loc[lambda ]`:

```
(df.explode('Combinations')
   .loc[lambda x: x.Combinations.ne(keyword) & 
            x.Combinations.eq(keyword).groupby(level=0).transform('any')]
)
```

Output:

```
   Combinations  Count
6          IDLY   2020
9     CHAPPATHI   1297
13         VADA   1141
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for your inputs , 'Combinations' column is actually of the type 'str'. I converted it from tuple to type str. Also while trying this out, i got an empty df as OP, does the type of series affect the code ?

Comment: Yes, `explode` works for the original `tuples` type. String type does not work. In your case, apply this approach to the original data with `tuples`.

Comment: Is there a way to do a similar thing for str type , because while reading from CSV , the dtype of 'Combinations' column is of type str

Comment: `df['Combinations'] = df.Combinations.str.findall("'([^']*)'")` will give you your tuple data back.

Answer (score 1):

you can also try creating a dataframe as a reference , then mask where keyword matches with `stack` for dropping NaN:

```
keyword = 'DOSA'

m = pd.DataFrame(df['Combinations'].tolist(),index=df.index)
c = m.eq(keyword).any(1)
df[m.eq(keyword).any(1)].assign(Combinations=
                         m[c].where(m[c].ne(keyword)).stack().droplevel(1))
```

---

```
   Combinations  Count
6          IDLY   2020
9     CHAPPATHI   1297
13         VADA   1141
```

For string type, you can convert into tuple by:

```
import ast
df['Combinations'] = df['Combinations'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

Answer (score 1):

What I will do

```
x=df.explode('Combinations')
x=x.loc[x.index[x.Combinations=='DOSA']].query('Combinations !="DOSA"')
x
   Combinations  Count
6          IDLY   2020
9     CHAPPATHI   1297
13         VADA   1141
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = df[df['Combinations'].transform(lambda x: 'DOSA' in x)].copy()
d['Combinations'] = d['Combinations'].apply(lambda x: set(x).difference(['DOSA']).pop())
print(d)
```

Prints:

```
   ID Combinations  Count
1   6         IDLY   2020
2   9    CHAPPATHI   1297
5  13         VADA   1141
```